# Cannot access my Asp.Net Api from the Internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, api, nginx

I made an Api using Asp.Net and lauched it on my Ubuntu VPS. I can access it locally using localhost, but when i try to access it using ip, i get the connection refused error. I tried setting up nginx, now it redirects from port 80 to port 5000, but i still get the connection refused error. Why is my Api not accessible remotely from the Internet? I spent a whole working day trying to solve this, and I am desperate at this point.
Here is the link to my question about nginx: [Asp.Net + Nginx. Works if using localhost, but fails if using ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70169749/asp-net-nginx-works-if-using-localhost-but-fails-if-using-ip)

Answer (score 3):

Solved: I needed to use the command line argument --urls http://*:5000

Comment: is there still redirect from 80 to 5000 ?

Comment: Utarid, I don't remember any details anymore, that was very long ago.